# How to execute grep -v -e 'expr1' and grep -e 'expr2' at the same command?

Tags: grep, string

I have the following command to extract string that do not start with `www.` and do not contain `/`:

```
grep -v -e '^www\.' -e '/' test2.txt
```

But I want the above in addition to matching `somestring.somestring` pattern, which can be achieved with this command:

```
grep -e '^[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$'
```

How to put all theses into one line?

Comment: `[^\.]` matches on collating elements other than `.` and backslash, is it really what you want? I suspect you want to match on lines that contain one and only one dot instead.

Comment: I want one dot only. Example: `gmail.com`, `google.com`. But `[^\.]` is to exclude literal dot but does not exclude the backslash. The backslash is used to express literal dot because it is a special character in reges (if I do not add \, the dot is interpreted as "any character". With backslash, it interpreted as dot).

Comment: No `.` is always litteral inside brackets. If you add a backslash, then the backslash becomes part of the set as well.

Comment: Try it: `( echo 'backslash \'; echo 'dot .'; ) | grep -e '[.]'`  (or with `grep '[\.]'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't combine reverse and forward matches in one `grep` invocation

You can do it with `sed`:

```
sed -e '/^www\./d' -e '/\//d' -e '/^[^.]*\.[^.]*$/!d' ./*.txt
```

Or `awk` (which contrary to `sed` would be able to print the name of the matching file like `grep`):

```
awk -F. 'NF == 2 && !/^www\./ && !/\// {print FILENAME": "$0}' ./*.txt
```

You could do it with two grep invocations provided you don't want the file names to be printed:

```
cat ./*.txt | grep '^[^.]*\.[^.]*$' | grep -v -e / -e '^www\.'
```

Here using `cat` to feed the content of all the files on stdin so the first `grep` doesn't print the file names. Some `grep` implementations have `grep -h` to skip printing the file names if there's more than one file. In the case of only one file name, `grep` doesn't print the file name anyway, and you can feed it on its stdin with redirections:

```
<onefile.txt grep '^[^.]*\.[^.]*$' | grep -v -e / -e '^www\.'
```

You could implement negation with PCRE's `(?!...)` negative look-ahead operators if your `grep` supports `-P`:

```
grep '^(?!www\.)(?!.*/)[^.]*\.[^.]*$' ./*.txt
```

But here, you could do it all with `-v` with:

```
grep -v -e / -e '^www\.' -e '^[^.]*$' -e '\..*\.'
```

That is also exclude lines that contain no dot and lines that contain more than one dot.

Comment: Thanks. It looks a bit complex. If piping will work (not wrong) I will use it. The question is shall I use the file name in each command? i.e. `grep -v -e '^www\.' -e '/' test2.txt | grep -e '^[^.]*\.[^.]*$' test2.txt > result.txt` OR `grep -v -e '^www\.' -e '/' test2.txt | grep -e '^[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$' > result.txt`. I know I can test it but with toy examples it can not show exactly what will happen in the large file. I want to make sure as I'm not Linux familiar.

Comment: @user9371654, see edit.

Comment: Thanks. I would go with: `cat ./*.txt | grep '^[^.]*\.[^.]*$' | grep -ve / -ve '^www\.'` But Ihave two questions: can I eliminate the cat?  i.e. using the file name after the first grep command which includes the file name: `grep '^[^.]*\.[^.]*$' myfile.txt` then in the next command after the piping `|` I do not use the file name?

Comment: @user9371654, you want the second `grep` to grep the output of the first grep, not of the file. My answer covers how to eliminate the `cat` (in the  case of only one file, or with the non-standard `-h` for more than one file).

Comment: `<onefile.txt grep '^[^.]*\.[^.]*$' | grep -v -e / -e '^www\.'` provides similar result to: `grep '^[^.]*\.[^.]*$' onefile.txt | grep -v -e / -e '^www\.'` ?? or are there differences?

Answer (score 2):

Pipe the first `grep`'s result into the second `grep`.

Comment: Can you provide the command please?